# Chapter only in TOC not in body of document

Tags: table-of-contents, renewcommand

Is there a renew command or similar for chapter so I can suppress the chapter name from showing up in the body of the document, but does show up in table of content?

This is the closest I got, but then I need to use it for each chapter, would be nice to just do it in one place for the whole document.

`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter name as its displayed in toc}`

The context is I'm writing a poetry collection and want the name of the poems to only show in table of contents.

Comment: How do you currently display your poems in your document? Do you use something like `\begin{center} Some poem name \end{center}`? What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner Thank you for reaching out, this one already got solved. I posted my full solution in the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter name as its displayed in toc}
    Some text
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATED** after follow up question

This code allows you to use the `\chapter` command. It does not generate the chapter headings in the document, but will display them in the TOC. You might also suppress the chapter number.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
 
% ******************************** added <<<<
 \usepackage{xpatch} 
 \makeatletter
 \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\@chapapp\space\thechapter}{}{}{}
 \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{#1}{}{}{}
 %\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}}{}{}{}  % OPTIONAL supress chapter number <<<<
 \makeatother
%************************************* 

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
        
    \chapter{chapter name as its displayed in toc}
    
    Some text
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Ideally though I would like a renew command or similar so I could keep it as \chapter{} like it was before (because I'm using Org Mode). If not possible I will either switch to plain latex (or in Org Mode use the #+begin_export latex instead of ** for each chapter).

Comment: @qwerty Do you want the chapter number in the TOC as well or just the chapter title?

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. The chapter number I found how to suppress already:
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{}{}{\itshape\bfseries}{\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]

Comment: @qwerty It might be easier just by adding  `\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}}{}{}{}`. See the OPTIONAL in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Simon Dispa's response this is solved now! I will add my end setup here in case somebody stumbles over this in the future:

So in plain LaTeX it would be

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=black}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{#1}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{}{}{\itshape\bfseries}{\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]
\author{Charles Bukowski}
\date{\today}
\title{Poetry Collection\\\medskip
\large Template}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\setstretch{1.2}
\chapter{now}
\begin{verse}
I sit here on the 2nd floor\\\empty
hunched over in yellow\\\empty
pajamas\\\empty
still pretending to be\\\empty
a writer.\\\empty
\end{verse}

\chapter{next poem}
\begin{verse}
WRITE HERE\ldots{}\\\empty
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

However, I'm using Org Mode, so here's how I set that up:

First, the setupfile (to avoid cluttering the main document)

```
# POETRY COLLECTION SETUPFILE
# Saved as poetry-collection-setupfile.org in same directory as main org document

#+LATEX_CLASS:  book
# Table of content (toc:nil to disable)
#+OPTIONS: toc:t
# Needed for setstretch
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{setspace}
# Needed for titlecontents
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{titletoc}
# Needed for xpatchcmd
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xpatch}
# Links without color
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{hyperref}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=black}

# Remove chapter showing in body of document (depends on xpatch package)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \makeatletter
#+LATEX_HEADER: \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\@chapapp\space\thechapter}{}{}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{#1}{}{}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \makeatother

# Remove header and give a more clean minimal look in general
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagestyle{plain}

# Remove "Part" (first level heading is ignored)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\part}[1]{}

# Comfortable line spacing (depends on setspace package)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setstretch{1.2}

# Remove numbering for "Chapters" in table of content (depends on titletoc)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{}{}{\itshape\bfseries}{\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]
```

Then, the main file:

```
#+title: Poetry Collection
#+subtitle: Template
#+author: Charles Bukowski
#+date: \today
#+setupfile: ./poetry-collection-setupfile.org

# First level headings are ignored (i.e. no Parts in exported pdf)
* Some reference for you only while writing

# Second headline exported as chapter in latex pdf
** now
#+begin_verse
I sit here on the 2nd floor
hunched over in yellow
pajamas
still pretending to be
a writer.
#+end_verse

** next poem
#+begin_verse
WRITE HERE...
#+end_verse
```

Additionally, if wanting table of content at the end instead of after the title, set toc:t to toc:nil in setupfile and then by the very end of the main document you need to add

```
#+begin_export latex
\tableofcontents
#+end_export
```